# Open and read files in directory inside folder in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

Okay guys so I am a bit lost as to how to adjust my code. Up to now, I have my code to read any Json file in a directory, parse it and put it in a table - works great since I was only using 1 JSON file per table row.

What I need to do now is the following, each IP address I have gives me 3 JSON files now that are placed into a folder with the IP address as its name. In my main directory I will have many folder each with 3 JSON files in it.

I want to read each file in every folder, place the info I parse in a table and then move on to the next folder as a new row and do the same.

```
FOR REFERENCE::

Current file layout:
FOLDER-->JSON
      -->JSON
      -->JSON

New file layout:
FOLDER-->IPADDRESS-->JSONFILE1
                  -->JSONFILE2
                 -->JSONFILE3

      -->IPADDRESS2-->JSONFILE1
                   --JSONFILE2
                   -->JSONFILE3
```

Current code for reading any JSON file in a directory:

```
 $dir = "my dir";
 if (is_dir($dir)) {
   if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
     foreach(glob("*_name.json") as $filename) {
       $data = file_get_contents($filename);
       $testing = json_decode($data, true);
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>{$filename }</td>";
       foreach($testing[0] as $row) {
         // code for parsing here ...
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go using RecursiveIteratorIterator Class

```
  function Get_Files()
  {

      $dir = "my_dir";
      $init = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));

      $files = array();

      foreach ($init as $file) {

          if ($file->isDir()) {
              continue;
          }

              $files[] = $file->getPathname();


      }

      return $files;
  }


foreach (Get_Files() as $file) {
 $data = file_get_contents($file);
$testing = json_decode($data, true);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$file}</td></tr>";


}
```

output:

```
my_dir\192.168.0.1\JSONFILE1.json
my_dir\192.168.0.1\JSONFILE2.json
```